# How do I do a random sample of a specific number of cases of each value?

Tags: spss, sampling

I have a data set with numerous cases of a dichotomous variable (0 or 1). Is there a way in SPSS to ask for a random sample of 500 cases with the value of 0 and 500 cases with the value of 1 (1000 total)? Essentially trying to get a random sample with an even amount of cases for each value.

I've searched through IBM's website and tons of YouTube videos and can't seem to find anything like this, though it sounds simple.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a random variable, rank by that variable, and keep 500 cases of each category according to their rank:

```
compute rndm=uniform(1).
RANK VARIABLES=rndm (A) BY yourdichovar  /RANK  /PRINT=NO  /TIES=MEAN.
select if Rrndm<=500.
exe.
```